# Sending the mail using c# with attachment to webmail throw exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to create *Contact Us* form using `asp.net`. I am trying to send mail with attachment, but it is giving me following error/exception -

> User not local; please try a different path. The server response was: Sender address is not valid for your login. Check your email program settings.

I need to be **from** address must be user type in `TextBox` email address and I also want to know that is there any plugin to sending the mail?

Below is my code.. Need help

***Code behind***

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
        //Sender e-mail address.
        Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtemail.Text);
        //Recipient e-mail address.
        Msg.To.Add("admin@comapany.com");
        //Meaages Subject
        Msg.Subject = "";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Name :" + txtname.Text + "\r\n");
        sb.Append("Contact:" + txtcontact.Text + "\r\n");
        sb.Append("Email:" + txtemail.Text + "\r\n");
        sb.Append("Message:" + txtmessage.Text + "\r\n");
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
           string FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
           Msg.Attachments.Add(new      Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));

        }
        Msg.Body = sb.ToString();
        // SMTP server IP.
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        //smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        //smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.Host = "webmail.sarvajteq.com";
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.Credentials = new   System.Net.NetworkCredential("******","*********");
        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
        smtp.Send(Msg);
        //Mail Message
        Response.Write("<Script>alert('Thanks for posting your resume us,our team will be contact you as soon as possible')</Script>");
        // Clear the textbox values
        txtname.Text = "";
        txtcontact.Text = "";
        txtemail.Text = "";
        txtmessage.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txtname.Text = "";
        txtcontact.Text = "";
        txtemail.Text = "";
        txtmessage.Text = "";
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

***aspx***

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <fieldset style="width: 400px;">
            <legend>Career Form</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Conatct Number
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontact" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Email
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Message
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtmessage" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Resume Upload
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click"
                            Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Width="200px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please use the tags properly !

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: @Bob "User not local; please try a different path. The server response was: Sender address is not valid for your login. Check your email program settings. " error message

Comment: @kittysarvaj That should be part of the question itself, we shouldn't have to ask you for those details. Please review [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is `webmail.sarvajteq.com` your own server? The error message looks very clear to me. You probably have insufficient rights to use that server for SMTP. That you can use webmail does not mean you can connect to it to send mail from another domain\server\website.

Comment: i have hostgator windows server,this web-mail services is provided by hostgator,i want to create the contact us page but its throwing error.